# What is the mathematical symbol for range?

Tags: notation

<sup>An unsophisticated question from a neophyte:</sup>

Given the numbers: $1,2,3,4,5$

> What is the ***symbol for the range*** of the numbers?

i.e. the lowest-highest number in the set.  For example, the min max is $1-5$.

The ____ is $1-5$. (insert math symbol into blank).

Should such a beast exist, I'd be particularly interested in it's unicode character...

Tried searching a few online resources, such as: http://rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Basic_Math_Symbols.htm without success.

Comment: $\{1,...,5\} $ works, but I don't believe there is a single symbol to denote the range.

Comment: I think that both of the current answers miss the heart of the question.  It seems like OP is looking for a notation that means "the smallest interval containing a given subset $S \in \mathbb R$", or similar thereto.

Comment: An finite ordered set of $n$ elements is called a $n$-tuple, and is commonly denoted with parenthesis, e.g. $(1,2,...,5)$ for the 5-tuple of 1 to 5. But this notation clashes with open intervals, when working with 2-tuples. So you should probably add some explanatory text depending on who your target audience is.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are looking for either:

1. A **closed interval**: $[a,b]$ represents the set of all real numbers greater or equal to $a$ and less or equal to $b$.
2. A **integer interval**: $[a\ldotp\ldotp b]$ represents all integers in between $a$ and $b$. ($[1\ldotp\ldotp 5] = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$)

Comment: This however are just "unordered" sets. What if I want to represent a list of numbers that go from 1 to 5? Conventionally that is written 1-5, which can be confused with a minus. In programming you use 1:5, which can be confused with the "such that" symbol in math. I don't know of other signs that might be less confusing than these two.

Answer (score 30):

This is a useful [wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)).

It is important to make the distinction between whether or not a particular endpoint is included. Use ( or ) to exclude and [ or ] to include.

For instance

$$(a,b) \;\;\Rightarrow \;\; \{x\in\Bbb R:a<x<b\}$$
$$[a,b] \;\;\Rightarrow  \;\;\{x\in\Bbb R:a\le x\le b\}$$
$$\{a..b\} \;\;\Rightarrow  \;\;\{x\in\Bbb Z:a\le x\le b\}$$

Comment: Does that mean that I can write something like $\varphi\in[0,\pi]$ (and be generally understood)?

Comment: @MadPhysicist absolutely

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add to Henricus answer as it gives the answer for a integer range but not for ranges of general step sizes, which is something that is very common in programming.

The expression

$$\{s k \mid k \in [a..b] \}$$
would give you a range from $sa$ to $sb$ with increments of s.

So if you wanted to write an expression for the numbers $$\{-3,-2.5, -2, -1.5, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3\}$$
that could be written as $$\{\frac{1}{2} k \mid k \in [-6..6] \}.$$